# Mongoose query populate match id of find elements

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to populate a model with data from another model. Those two models looks like this:

```
var postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _comments: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' },
    type: String,
    body: String,
});

var commentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    id_post: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    body: String,
});
```

I want to find all `posts` and populate them with `comments` that have `id_post` == `_id` from founded Posts. Something like this:

```
Post.find({}).populate({
    path: '_comments',
    select: 'body',
    match: { post_id: Post._id }
    options: { limit: 5 }
})
.exec(function (err, posts){...});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, There are few problems in the code you wrote.
If each post may have many comments you should implement one-to-many relationship between your schemas, you can do it by surrounding the comment ref with []

```
var postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _comments:  [ {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment'} ] ,
    type: String,
    body: String,
});
```

id_post is not just a field of type ObjectId, it should be written like this:

```
var commentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
post: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post' },
body: String,
});
```

When saving a new comment make sure you connect it to its post:

```
var comment = new Comment({
    body: "Hello",
    post: post._id    // assign the _id from the post
  }); 

comment.save(function (err) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    // thats it!
  });
```

Now when you want to find a post and populate its comments you should write something like this:

```
Post
.find(...)
.populate({
  path: '_comments',
  select: 'body',
  options: { limit: 5 }
})
.exec()
```

The reason I dropped the match is that match should be used when you want to filter according to a specific field, in your case you can use match to get only comments with type='something'.

populate should work because when you inserted the comment you made the bond to its post.

More information on the right way of using populate can be found here - [Mongoose Query Population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

Post data should be persisted the following way:

```
{
   body: "some body",
   type: "some type",
   _comments: [12346789, 234567890, ...]
}
```

More information about the way the ref will be persisted here - [One-to-Many Relationships with Document References](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/)

Comment: `_comments` from `postSchema` should contain something like `[ { _id: Comment.id } ]` ? or `[ { id_post: Post._id } ]`

Comment: You can find the modified postSchema in my answer, I have just added the commentSchema with the right way to relate it to its Post.

Comment: In my DATABASE what a `post` document would look like ? `_comments` what should contain ?

Comment: Our Person model has it's stories field set to an array of ObjectIds.
As for how it will be persisted, have a look here:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/

Comment: Edited my answer to answer all your additional questions from your comments.